# Coldfusion on Linux - Postfix to send mail - what to put in Coldfusion Administrator?

Tags: linux, coldfusion, centos, postfix-mta, cfmail

I'm running Coldfusion on centos 5.5. To send mail I've got postfix setup as a [null client](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client). I can send mail fine from the command line, but I'm unsure of what to put in the Coldfusion Administrator under the "Mail Server Settings" section. It's asking for these fields specifically:

```
Mail Server     
User name       
Password
```

Or would I put them within the `<cfmail>` tag? That would not be ideal as I have cfmail tags throughout the site/server. Any ideas what I should do to send mail with `<cfmail>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mailserver setting should be the same as `myhostname` in your postfix configuration. You only need to supply username and password if the mailserver requires authentication.

You should definitely put these in the CF Administrator if possible to save repeating (and managing) them in every `cfmail` tag.

(Disclosure - I don't use postfix a lot and have inferred the myhostname settings required from [here](https://articles.slicehost.com/2009/9/29/centos-postfix-basic-settings-in-main-cf))

Comment: You can use <CFINCLUDE> or <CFMODULE> for the <cfmail>, so that you only write that code once. Anyway, your reply is the correct answer!